# Как проверить пусто массив после сплита

Tags: python, telebot

[image: Код]

Есть вот такой код, в случае если вводить сообщение без аргумента питон выдает ошибку что нету этого в массиве, что естественно, как можно реализовать это?

Comment: `if len(message.text.split(" ")) and ...`

Comment: `args[1] in args` - не имеет смысла. Если он не падает, то всегда возвращает истину.

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев `len` тут излишне

Comment: @CrazyElf вы правы, но не самым опытным так может быть понятнее